# time complexity of algorithm to sort names using the bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

A machine took 200 sec to sort 200 names using the bubble sort. Then in 800 sec how many names will be sorted.Please help me to solve this. I tried to solve it using the time complexity of bubble sort but i am unable to do it

and also want to find the complexity of the following code

```
    int somefunct(int n)
    {
      if(n<=2)
        return 1;
      else
       return (somefunct(floor(sqrt(x)))+x);
     }
```

Comment: 800 = 4 * 200; sqrt(4) = 2, so you can sort twice as many as before (400 names).

Comment: How long are the names? What is the probablity that 1 first letter is the same, 2 letters are the same, etc ? Without such info is really hard to estimate unless you assuming string comparation is done in `O(1)` ... Also without knowing the state of disorder of your data is hard to tell ... complexity of bubble sort is `O(n^2)` but that is only for reverse ordered data which is highly improbable. So you need to add REALLY WILD ASSUMPTIONS to compute this

Answer (score 1):

Since the time to sort by a bubble-sort in the worst case is a polynomial of degree 2 in n, we have:

`t = an^2 + bn + c`

Now, since n is big enough (200 here), so we can ignore the last two terms to get:

`t = an^2`

Put the values: `t = 200` and `n = 200` to get `a = 1/200`

Therefore, in 800 seconds, you'll be able to sort atmost:

`800 = (1/200)*(n^2)`

`=> n = 400` names

Atmost because this is the worst case scenario.

Comment: Sorry Jim, I missed it. Edited the answer now.

Comment: O(n^2) doesn't mean the exact formula is a polynomial. For example it could be 't = a*n^2 + b*n*log(n) or something even weirder. (Of course, your logic is otherwise correct that the n^2 term will eventually dominate the other terms and that's clearly what this homework question intended.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'll correct the write-logic. Though for a bubble sort, the polynomial relation will hold true.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of bubble sort is `O(n^2)` in worst case. Thus in 4 times the given time it will sort twice the current names. ie. 400 names in 800sec in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting 200 names, bubble sort makes 200 * 199/2 = 19900 comparisons.
The time needed for 1 comparison is 200 sec. In 800 sec it can make 80,000 comparisons.
We have to find n,such that n(n-1)/2=80,000. => n^2 - n = 160000.  Last term can be neglected. Therefore, n^2 = 160000 . Answer= 400.

Comment: *"The time needed for 1 comparison is 200 sec."* I'm sure you meant something else, because if one comparison takes 200 seconds, then you can only make four comparisons in 800 seconds. In any case, it's not really necessary to count comparisons, when you can solve the problem simply enough just using the time and estimated algorithmic complexity (n^2).